# texify.exe in TeXworks in MSWindows 10: MiKTex encountered internal error when compile with --shell-escape

Tags: xetex, windows, minted

I try to compile a tex text using the `minted` package using TeXworks and choosing the option `XeLaTex+MakeIndes+BibTeX`.

When i try to build as is I get the error:

```
! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.102 \newminted
                {cpp}{texcomments}
?
```

When I add the `--shell-escape` argument as you can see in  the image bellow:

[image]

I get the error:

```
ERROR: MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
ERROR: Info: 
ERROR: Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session/SessionImpl.h
ERROR: Line: 617

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

Do you know how I will fix it? I use the following sample to build:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin={0.07\paperwidth,0.07\paperwidth}]{geometry}

\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\newminted{json}{texcomments}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{jsoncode}
{
 otaku=true,
 anime_types=['echi','harem','hentai' ]
}
\end{jsoncode}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

And I have installed both `python` and `pygments` python dependencies.

Comment: Note it is **really not recommended** to add `--shell-escape` to your default tex options. Just make a special configuration that uses that. there are good reasons why `--shell-escape` is disabled by default.

Comment: So what alternative you suggest to compile XeLateX with minted in TexWorks?

Comment: as you show, but not using the standard `xelatex` configuration, use a new `xelatex+shell-escape` configuration.  If you always use shell-escape then you are trusting that any tex code that you ever copy from some random internet site is safe and will not delete all the files on your hard disk, or mail them to some spam network or anything else. `xetex --shell-escape` means you allow the document to take full control of your machine, it can run any program that you can run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option should get provided via `--tex-option` parameter thus the option that should be inserted should be:

```
--tex-option=--shell-escape
```

As image shows bellow:

[image: Setting up options in XeLaTex]